# Define a function and use it in a SQL-Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I was tring to create a function and use it in my little Query. I did not do this before and I do not really know to do it.

Is it simply the same like any other languages?
like

```
create function testFunction()...
begin
..
..
end
```

and then for example :

```
Select testFunction()
```

and it should work ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ISOweek (@DATE datetime)  
RETURNS int  
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @ISOweek int
     SET @ISOweek= DATEPART(wk,@DATE)+1  
          -DATEPART(wk,CAST(DATEPART(yy,@DATE) as CHAR(4))+'0104')
--Special cases: Jan 1-3 may belong to the previous year  
     IF (@ISOweek=0)   
          SET @ISOweek=dbo.ISOweek(CAST(DATEPART(yy,@DATE)-1   
               AS CHAR(4))+'12'+ CAST(24+DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS CHAR(2)))+1
--Special case: Dec 29-31 may belong to the next year  
     IF ((DATEPART(mm,@DATE)=12) AND   
          ((DATEPART(dd,@DATE)-DATEPART(dw,@DATE))>= 28))  
          SET @ISOweek=1
     RETURN(@ISOweek)
END;  
GO  
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT dbo.ISOweek(CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/26/2004',101)) AS 'ISO Week'
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in SQL Server Books Online?

Comment: I did! too many examples but nothing worked somehow that is why i am asking here. Maybe i miss something..

Comment: well please show the function and how you tried to use it, and what errors (or, if no errors, what unexpected behaviour) you got. Otherwise we've no idea what you did wrong. "Not working" is not a problem description. And that sample above is the most basic bit and unlikely to be the real problem.

Comment: You cannot write a function in pascal and then expect it to work in SQL, they are two different environments. (Unless you are using delphi, firedac and sqlite, but that is beside the point). I suggest you read up on `stored procedure`s, preferably specific to the database you use, MSSQL as you tagged it. (and I hope youre not dumping your homework on us).

Comment: I am not dumping my homework on you that is why i asked in general how to create and call a function in SQL. :)

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu Take it easy

Comment: Hi memo_star, looks like you are writing a function that need to return a scalar value, is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SQL functions are easy to create. But you have to understand the 3 different types of functions in SQL:
1) **Scalar functions:**
-- return a single value.
2) **Table based functions:**
-- returns a Table.
3) **Aggregate function:**
returns a single value (but the function looped through a window set).

creating a function in MS SQL Server 2012 by using template:
[image: Creating Function with the MS SQL Server Client]

There some great reference resources for starting creating SQL functions: 
an example of User Defined Scalar Function (from [dotnettricks](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/different-types-of-sql-server-functions)):

```
        --Create function to get emp full name 
        Create function fnGetEmpFullName
        (
          @FirstName varchar(50),
          @LastName varchar(50)
        )
        returns varchar(101)
        AS
        BEGIN 
          return (Select @FirstName + ' '+ @LastName);
        END
```

Microsoft reference, explanation and examples in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions)
informit article on User Defined Functions in this [link2](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31673&seqNum=4)
and finally from SQL Team website, an introduction to [User Defined Functions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/intro-to-user-defined-functions-updated)

Comment: Great tutorial :-)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit broad, do you want to return a table? a value?.. There are many different things that a `function` can do, a sample syntax would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Schema.FunctionName
(
@InputValue InputValueDataType --Parameters here
)
RETURNS ReturnDataType -- The data type you want to return it
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do some things with @InputValue
END
```

The Microsoft Doc is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) it explains the different ways to do it

Then you can just do `SELECT * FROM schema.FunctionName (@InputValue)` to return it